# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 CD errors

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04, snap, cd

When trying to load Ubuntu Studio 22.04 from CD I get the following errors.

```
Failed to Start: Thermal Daemon Service
Failed to Start: SNAP Daemon
Failed to Start: CUPS Daemon
Failed to Start: Network Manager
...
```

The system never boots after that.

In Safe Mode, the system boots, but wifi setup doesn't work. It can't find any routers.

- HP desktop
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700F CPU @ 2.90GHz
- 32GB RAM
- Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI   Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
- Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems addressed in the [Ubuntu Studio 22.04 Release Notes](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/):

> NOTE: This ISO image exceeds 4.0GB and might not write correctly to a DVD. **We recommend USB flash drives be used as installation media**.

Try installing using a recommended method, and see if that cures your wifi problem also.